# D flip flop in verilog

Tags: verilog, flipflop

When i tried to code the below flip flop, the program failed. I'm using altera .

[image]

```
module DFF_SYNC_RESET(Din, nRst, Dout, Clk);
output Dout;
input nRst,Clk,Din;

wire D;
assign D= Din & nRst;

always@(posedge Clk)
 begin 
  Dout<= D;
end

endmodule
```

Can you please tell my failure in the code?
[image]

Edit: After i encountered to another problem which is the same as in this page, the problem was solved

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832326/altera-quartus-error-12007-top-level-design-entity-alt-ex-1-is-undefined

Comment: You should make `D` a `wire` and use a syntactically correct assignment like`assign D = Din & nRst;`.

Comment: thanks. I did but this time it threw these errors

Comment: "DFF_SYNC_RESET cannot be declared more than once". You have more than one module with that name in your project

Comment: this time it threw another error.left hand side of assignment must have a variable data type. thanks anyway, if the code seems okey, it is okey. i'll ask this to the lecturer

Comment: @"DFF_SYNC_RESET cannot be declared more than once": Do you include this file in other files? The new error is quite clear, there is another module with the same name defined elsewhere in your design.

Comment: i saved the file with a different name and that error disappeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Verilog, if you assign to something in a procedural block (a block between `begin` and `end`), you need to make it a regsiter type. If you assign to something in a continual assignment (either an `assign` statement or the output of an instance of a module) you need to make it a wire type.

So you need to declare (You already edited this change into your question)

```
wire D;
```

on line 5, and

```
output reg Dout;
```

on line 2.

Also, `D` is somewhat superfluous. You could just have

```
output reg Dout
...
always @(posedge clk) begin
    Dout <= Din & nRst;
end
```

Even better, you should not use logic to simulate control features on flip-flops if your architecture makes full-featured flip-flops available. To code a DFF with syncronous reset for synthesis you would rather have

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if ~nRst 
         Dout <= 1'b0;
    else
         Dout <= Din;
end
```

This will be more likely to use the built in features of the flip-flops in your architecture, resulting in faster and more resource-efficient implementation.

The error you showed doesn't seem to relate to how you defined your DFF_SYNC_RESET module. More likely it has to do with what files you are including in the synthesis or where you instantiated it, either in your testbench or in a higher-level module.